# How can I encapsulate code dealing with matrices and make it reusable?

Tags: c++, function, class, header, structure

At my course we are getting tasks that always start with filling a random matrix size *nxm* with random numbers.

I want to create(a library?, a class?) some structure so than any time I want to generate a matrix *A* I would need  just to input the desired size *nxm*.

In other words, change all this code for something like  `#include <myrandommatrixgenerator>`.

```
int n, m;

cout << "Enter number of rows (n): ";
cin >> n;
cout << "Enter number of columns (m): ";
cin >> m;

//matrix b with random numbers
srand(time(NULL));

int max = 9, min = -9;

int *b = new int[n*m];
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<m; j++)
    {
        b[i*m + j] = min + ((rand() % max) + 1);
    }
}

//print matrix b
cout << "\nMatrix b:" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<m; j++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << b[i*m + j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I do not have a broad overview of the possibilities with C++, **so what is the structure that allow me to do that?**

Comment: A side note: it's better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an outline of what you can do to achieve that:

1. Define a class e.g. `MyMatrix`. A [class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes) can encapsulate data and operations related to it. The class can be placed in separate files (h and cpp). A friendly guide: [C++ Classes and Objects - w3schooles](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_classes.asp).
2. This class should use e.g. a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to hold the data (better than using raw pointers like in your code).
3. This class should have public methods for getting the metadata (n,m) and data.
4. This class should have a public method, e.g.: `InitRandom(int n, int m)`, to initialize the `MyMatrix` object to a matrix size n x m with random values.
5. In another part of your program you can `#include` your class h file, and then instantiate a `MyMatrix` object, and use `InitRandom` to do what you need.

You can see here a discussion about implementing a matrix class: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155811/basic-matrix-class-in-c